# myVar = false setting myVar to true?

Tags: c#

I thought I was going mad this morning and was about to section myself, but then decided to just ask someone else to take a look at a piece of code for me, and 2 colleagues have confirmed either I'm not mad, or we are all mad.

I've got the following code:

```
bool isStaffMember = false;

using (var uam = new ReadOnlyADUserAccountManager(adUser.Domain.ShortName))
{
    var props = uam.GetLocalUserProperties(adUser, new string[] { "IsStaff" });
    if (props.Count > 0 && props.ContainsKey("IsStaff") && props["IsStaff"] != null && props["IsStaff"].Value.ToString() == "1")
        isStaffMember = true;
    else
        isStaffMember = false;
}

var validGroups = GetValidUserGroups(adUser.Sid);
```

For some reason I found that by the time reached the last line of code, isStaffMember was always true. So I put in some breakpoints.

On stepping through, isStaffMember remains as the default value of false, up until the point it hits the line "isStaffMember = false;". Now, to me this should, I'm fairly certain, set isStaffMember to false (or leave it as false as it already was). But no, with the breakpoint on that line, I hit F10, it moves on to the last line in the code above, and suddenly isStaffMember is true. The GetValidUserGroups method hasn't run at this point (and wouldn't change the value anyway).

I'm slightly confused at why isStaffMember = false causes isStaffMember to become true.

Anyone seen this bizarre behaviour before and know what might be causing it?

if I type isStaffMember = false into the immediate window it works, and sets it to false.

Comment: Is this code multithreaded?

Comment: Where is this code running and how are you debugging it? I.e. is the code being debugged the code being run?

Comment: Add braces so the debugger will mark current line in a more readable way.

Comment: It is yeah. However, the other threads won't be processing the same code as once its started it sets a status on the task so that it can't be run again until its finished.

Comment: The code is being run on my local machine through Visual Studio 2010, I'm debugging using the F5 key, so it is definitely the code.

Comment: Are you compiling for release?

Comment: It is compiling for release (not sure why). However its fixed now with one of the other answers, but I'm going to do some more debugging of it just to figure out what exactly was happening. 

Thanks all for replies.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the debugger is setting the breakpoint for the whole if statement?

You can test it by changing your implementation to this:

```
bool isStaffMember = false;

using (var uam = new ReadOnlyADUserAccountManager(adUser.Domain.ShortName))
{
    var props = uam.GetLocalUserProperties(adUser, new string[] { "IsStaff" });
    var shouldBeStaffMember = props.Count > 0 && props.ContainsKey("IsStaff") 
          && props["IsStaff"] != null && props["IsStaff"].Value.ToString() == "1";

    //add breakpoint here
    isStaffMember = shouldBeStaffMember;
}

var validGroups = GetValidUserGroups(adUser.Sid);
```

Comment: Ah, that's done the trick, thanks. Really odd. 

Thanks for all the replies :)

Comment: I'll have to revert it temporarily and stick some braces in (as suggested by someone else) just to figure out what was going on (though this is obviously cleaner so will go back to using it).

Comment: I put some braces in around each part of the if statement, it still goes into the second part but sets it to true. Really weird.